# AngularJs sanitizing input

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular 1.6.4

```
var app = angular.module('a', ['ngSanitize']);


app.controller('BaseController', function($scope, $sce) {
   $scope.str = "<script>alert('hello world')</script>";
   $scope.sanitized = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.str);
});
```

I am trying to get a sanitized form of a string as the one above but it always returns the same $scope.str. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks-

This also did not remove the script tags

```
app.controller('BaseController', ['$scope', '$sce', function( $scope, $sce) {
    $scope.str = "<script>alert('hello world')</script>";
    $scope.sanitized = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.str);
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

A small glitch in your code that `$sce` should be injected in the controller level.

```
app.controller('BaseController', ['$sce', function($sce) {
    // ... [your code]
 }]);
```